# How to reorder a vector so it matches the order of another vector in R?

Tags: r

Pretty basic question that im struggling to find an answer on...

If I have two vectors in `R`, like so:

```
Name <- c(1,2,3,4)
Name_1 <- c(2,4,1,3)
```

Is there a way to reorder, say, the  `Name` vector so it matches the order of `Name_1`? 
That is, the resulting vector would look like this:

```
Result <- reorder(Name so that it = Name_1)
Result
> 2,4,1,3
```

Any suggestions as to how I do this in `R`?

Comment: You can just do `Name[Name_1]`.

Comment: You can get the order of a vector with ‘order’ so you can do Name[order(Name_1)].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all elements of Name_1 match with Name the 2 vectors are the same. However the solution should be:

```
Name[Name_1]
```

Comment: Thanks, this answers my initial question... but I think I'll have to ask a different question about applying this reordering to a matrix

Comment: This won’t work in the general case, for example if Name_1 is c(6, 8, 3, -125, 0)